# How do I run liquibase execute-sql using maven?

Tags: java, sql, maven, jdbc, liquibase

Liquibase has an `execute-sql` command, here's a summary from the [liquibase execute-sql docs](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/update/execute-sql.html)

> Use the execute-sql command to directly run SQL queries without changing and applying changelog files with changesets

I want to run the `execute-sql` command from maven but I don't think there's a maven goal for this.

The available maven goals are listed in the [liquibase maven goals docs](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/home.html)

> changelogSync, changelogSyncSQL, changelogSyncToTag, changelogSyncToTagSQL, checks.run, checks.show, clearCheckSums, dbDoc, deactivateChangeLog, diff, dropAll, flow, flow.validate, futureRollbackSQL, generateChangeLog, help, history, listLocks, registerChangeLog, releaseLocks, rollback, rollbackOneChangeSet, rollbackOneChangeSetSQL, rollbackOneUpdate, rollbackOneUpdateSQL, rollbackSQL, status, syncHub, tag, tagExists, unexpectedChangeSets, update, updateSQL, updateTestingRollback, validate

Is there any way to run `execute-sql` via maven?

Comment: did you somehow solve this issue?

Comment: I raised an issue on liquibase which is still open https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3793

Comment: My actual problem was that I had a "validate" changeset at the bottom of my main changelog that always runs last. I would then run liquibase:tag to tag my database but the tag was always applied to the "validate" changeset. As a workaround I moved the "validate" changeset to a totally seperate changelog. At deployment time I now run the main changelog, run liquibase:tag then run the "validate" changelog. So now I have tags on the last changeset for each release instead of the "validate" changeset being tagged